# Python Bkt - List index out of Range

Tags: python, arrays, range, out

I'm new in Python and I want to learn the Backtracking algorithm. I watched some tutorials and I created this code:

```
x = []
pod = []
class def_pod:
    ins1 = 0
    ins2 = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
ins_start = int(input("Insula de start: "))
n = int(input("Numar de poduri: "))
def Plimbare (insula_crt, k):
    if n==k:
        print(x)
    else:
        for i in range(0,n-1):
            if POSIBIL(i,k,insula_crt):
                x[k] = i
                if insula_crt == pod[i].ins1:
                    ins=pod[i].ins2
                else:
                    ins=pod[i].ins1
                Plimbare(ins,k+1)

def POSIBIL (alfa,k,ins_crt):
    for j in range(0,n-1):
        if x[j] == alfa:
            return False
    return pod[alfa].ins1 == ins_crt or pod[alfa].ins2 == ins_crt

print ("Lansare executie program: \n")
Plimbare(ins_start,0)
```

But I have some errors linked by the fact that my arrays are out of range and I don't know what I can do to solve this. Can you help me? I'm sorry if my question isn't so relevant but as I said, I'm new..

Comment: First time your `POSIBIL()` function called, `x` is empty list and you still want to access upto nth element in that list

Comment: instead of x[k] = i, use x.append(i)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think that my problem it's now solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Resolved in comments:
>
> ```
> First time your POSIBIL() function called, x is empty list and you still want to access upto nth element in that list 
>
> instead of x[k] = i, use x.append(i) – Jay Parikh
> ```